# Is is possible to host Silverlight widgets from a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, integration, widget, hosted

If I wanted to create some Silverlight widgets and host them within WPF is this possible?

I've searched for examples & found a few concepts online but no approaches that actually panned out / work / and a bunch of dead links.

Has anyone successfully done this *or* any ideas for how to do this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can try my [SilverlightViewport](http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com) project.  It allows for rendering Silverlight programs in WPF.  Should support all versions of SL.

Answer (score 0):

The brute approach would be using the WebBrowserControl. Other than that, I don't know. Maybe you could unzip the .XAP file and try to load the XAMLs and Assemblies you would find. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What features specific to Silverlight do you use in those widgets? Is there a real problem with making them work in both Silverlight and WPF and compiling 2 versions?